# what's shortcut key for switching current edited script to the last one?

Tags: matlab, keyboard-shortcuts

when several scripts opened, I have to switch between the calling script and called script and Test script, what's the shortcut the switch the two script quickly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/accessibility-use-keyboard-shortcuts-to-navigate-matlab.html), the closest you can get is navigating to the left/right of the current editor tab, so if you want to toggle between two or three files then ensure they are neighbouring tabs.

| Action | Keyboard Shortcut |
| --- | --- |
| Move to the next tab in a panel. | Ctrl+Page Down |
| Move to the previous tab in a panel. | Ctrl+Page Up |